# SQL: Is it possible to pass a data_type to a function in a variable? (Function CONVERT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I'm looking to call the `SQL CONVERT` function while referencing a variable to set the `data_type`.

For instance:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(10), column1, 120)
```

But instead of specifying `nvarchar(10)` I want to reference a variable:

```
CONVERT(@myDataType, column1, 120)
```

Now `@myDataType` might be `nvarchar(10)`, `nvarchar(7)` or `Int`, but I can't figure out the syntax to make that work.

Alternately, I'd like to set the size as a parameter so:

```
CONVERT(nvarchar(@mySize), column1, 120)
```

Where the size can be an `Int`. That doesn't seem to work either.

Are either of these possible?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your code is using product specific functionality.)

Comment: Not without dynamic SQL. What are you trying to accomplish by using this functionality?

Comment: This is in MSSQL using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: This query I run on occasion which uses CONVERT(nvarchar(10), column1, 120) multiple times. Sometimes I need to run it with CONVERT(nvarchar(7), column1, 120) instead. I was hoping to set a variable that I can tweak at the top, instead of doing a find/replace when i need to change it

Comment: The better question is why you store a datetime as a string. A computed column (maybe more than 1) might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do this.  Parameters only represent literal (i.e. "constant") values.  They do not represent identifiers, keywords, operators, and other components of the language.

In a stored procedure you could work around this using dynamic SQL.

However, SQL Server does not support (in any easy reasonable fashion) dynamic SQL in a function call.

I would suggest that you just convert to `nvarchar(max)` and then use `left()`:

```
LEFT(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), column1, 120), @mysize)
```

Actually, `nvarchar(max)` is a bit of overkill for dates.  A value such as `32` or `255` should be sufficient.

Comment: I like this idea. I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is basically static (as in - you won't change it a lot) you could write a dynamic sql statement to create the statement.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 

DECLARE @mySize INT = 10
DECLARE @q NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @q="
    SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar("+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@mySize)+"), column1, 120)"

PRINT @q
EXEC sp_executesql @q
```